# Excel Formula to compare single cell value with the whole column and return the value for a particular row where match found

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet-function

I need to compare the B2 Cell value (6012469) with Column A i.e. cell A2 to A10 and return the b2 cell value (6012469) in column C where the value matches i.e. cell C5,C7, C9 AND C10 and NA in remaining cells where the value is not matched.
I have around 15000 rows of data is column A and need to automate the process.

I have attached the sample image for reference.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DvzC3.png

Comment: Sounds like you are describing [`INDEX`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/index-function-a5dcf0dd-996d-40a4-a822-b56b061328bd) / [`MATCH`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/match-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a)

Comment: Hi Cybernetic.nomad, I tried using INDEX/MATCH but due to the large number of data it is time consuming. Can you please explain your answer. Thank you

Comment: do you mean time-consuming to write? or time-consuming to run? you only have 9 rows of data, so it's not clear what you mean by "large number of data"

Comment: Sorry for the confusion stifin, I have around 15000 rows of data

Comment: you could create a structured table, type a formula (to match with B2 value), and then _all 15000 rows_ in column C will automatically populate themselves and display the 6012469 if there is a match

Comment: Hi Stifin, can you please share the formula for same.

Answer (score 1):

Select any cell inside your data range in Column A. Go to your ribbon, click **Home** > **Format as Table**. It doesn't matter what colour scheme you choose.
[image: Create a structured table]

Make sure that all your data in Col A plus Cols B & C are included in the table.

Then, in any cell of your table in Col C (e.g. in C2), paste this formula:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($B$2,[@[Column A]])),$B$2,"")
```

Excel should automatically populate all of your Col C in the table with this formula. (If it doesn't, then you should see a little clickable prompt next to the cell asking if you want to overwrite all the other Col C cells with this formula.)

The table with the Col C formulas would look something like this:
[image: structured table with automatic formula replication]

Note: Of course, you could achieve something very similar without using a structured table, but not as conveniently as this because you would have to copy the formulas down to the other approx. 15000 rows. Even the **Fill Down** feature is not as convenient.

ADDITIONAL: a different formula in response to the asker's request that each cell in Column C match *any of multiple* values in Column B --

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$4,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH($B$2:$B$4,A2)),0)),"")
```

[image: modified formula for multiple Column B criteria]
NOTE: if more than one Column B value matches a Column A cell, Column C will display Column B's topmost match

Comment: By the way, it's handy when you ask a question to provide the data as text in your question. Not everyone is willing to retype everything out like I did just to help answer a question.

Comment: Hi Stifin, Thank you for the solution.
What I can use if I have multiple values in column b?
ex: b1= 6012469, b2= 2519396, b3 = 3690365
how can I return the same values in column c?

Comment: I'll add this to the answer if you can explain what you mean. Do you mean that c2 depends b2 as the criteria (6012469), c3 depends on b3 as the criteria (2519396), c4 depends on b4 as the criteria (36930365), etc? If that's what you mean, _all of col c in the example will be empty_

Comment: Hi Stifin, if I have different values in Columb B that are present in column A and I need to return those values in Column C 
Example:
Column A                                                Column B              Column C  
2519396/3113021                                    6012469                  NA               
1305177/1478337/1543953                     1478337               1478337         
2519396/6012569                                     3762229               6012569         
2519396/3690365;2519396/3762229                                    3762229

Comment: sorry, don't understand - tables don't display in Stack Overflow comments. Do you mean that each cell of column C should match _any_ of the values in column B and _show that matched value_?

Comment: Yes The value that are common in Column A and B must return that value in Column C at the same location i.e. cell where the match is found and display NA where match is not found.
If any two values (1305177/1478337)are common in Column A and B it must display both values in column C.

Comment: I never got around to answering this - if you want to ask something more suited to your needs, you can ask another question instead of repeatedly updating your requirements in one question (and not marking anything as answered)